# "I couldn't not do something" or "I couldn't have not done" in context?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if I need to say *I couldn't not do it* or *I couldn't have not done it*?

> My future career depended on the exam, so **I couldn't not pass it**.
>
> My future career depended on the exam, so **I couldn't have not passed it**.

What I am trying to say is that I passed it because it was absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These structures have different meanings and to me, the second sentence is somewhat unnatural.

I couldn't not pass it. = I had to pass it (because my career depended on it).

I couldn't have not passed it = I passed it (because it so easy it was impossible to fail).

Comment: I agree. These actually use different meanings of _could_: the first is necessity (_could_ = _must, had to_). The second is ability (_couldn't_ = _wasn't able to_).